# How to use Windows Terminal as Debugger console in Visual Studio 2019 for C++ Project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, windows-terminal

I have Visual C++ project. I Want to run/debug my console app in the new [Windows terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/) when the play button is clicked.

How can I configure this in Visual Studio 2019?

The Windows Terminal's path is

```
"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.4.3243.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\wt.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Windows Terminal as default terminal is not supported yet, see the **github issue** [Change Windows OS to support default terminal [defterm] · Issue #492 · microsoft/terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/492).

It seem to have no workaround in Visual Studio to use Windows Terminal ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65395740/11525112)) but if it makes sense to you, you might consider voting on that feature on [Kit Cragin's feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1293343/use-of-windows-terminal-during-debugging.html) in Developer Community.

As stated by staff working on the Windows Terminal [here](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/492#issuecomment-644143959), this feature is unlikely to be implemented anytime soon du to the early stage of the Windows Terminal.