# VS Debug Console

Tags: visual-studio

Is it be possible to not always open Debug Console in Visual Studio 2022, while running?
Just print in Output. [Debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNGqC.png)

Comment: Have you created a Console App?

Comment: Yes, I did. I tried to find some information about Debug Console, but it's not successful

Comment: It's possible with new Windows Terminal and with Windows 11. This forum could be helpful for you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56753339/how-to-use-the-new-windows-terminal-as-visual-studio-debugging-console

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.